# Как сделать возможность писать в определенном месте блокнота?

Tags: wpf

Создаю блокнот, на заднем фоне которого я поставил тетрадь в клетку. Как сделать, чтобы писать только по этим клеткам, не выходя из линии? А то я сделал, только в определенном месте буквы смещаются вверх, вниз и буквы записываются на клетках(гранях). Как сделать, чтобы пользователь не переходил и не писал на клетках, а писал внутри этих клеток?

P.S Да и еще? Как создаются такие блокноты??? Ну не с белым задним фоном, а с фоном в строчку, в клетку?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вам нужно, чтоб базовая линия шрифта совпадала с некоторой линией на фоне, так? Если да, то кроме того встает вопрос должен ли, блокнот поддерживать разные семейства шрифтов и разные размеры.

Comment: да, так. Нет, пока шрифт размер менять не надо

Answer (score 1):

Если шрифт менять не надо то для кисти используйте маленький рисунок (в размер, или чуть больше шрифта) который "подгоните" под шрифт. Это будет наиболее простое решение.

Comment: не получается. Все равно скользит со временем наверх

Comment: скользит... то-есть верхняя строка совпадает с рисунком, а чем ниже тем больше смещается вверх/вниз?

Comment: да да, точно!

Comment: Скорее всего вы неправильно подобрали высоту рисунка и/или положение линии на ней. Для вас важны два параметра кегль шрифта и расстояние от нижней кегельной линии до базовой линии -- если хоть в одном ошиблись буквы будут "скользить" по вертикали.
P.S. Размер шрифта и кегль в общем случае не совпадают